# SSH scp: cannot stat file, that seems to exist

Tags: ssh, scp

I have file on remote machine. I can list it:

```
ssh matous@xxx ls -la
```

the file is in the reponse:

```
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 matous matous 796672 Oct 11 11:12 D1.db
...
```

Now If I try to scp it to my local machine:

```
scp matous@xxx/D1.db /home/matous
```

I get error:

```
cp: cannot stat 'matous@x/D1.db': No such file or directory
```

How is it possible that file exists and cannot be stated? What I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax of scp is not correct. Try

```
scp matous@xxx:D1.db /home/matous
```

Without the colon (`:`), scp will try to interpret `matous@xxx/D1.db` as a local path.

Note that I omitted the leading `/`. If you would use `scp matous@xxx:/D1.db`, then `scp` would try to copy from `/D1.db` but this file appears to be in the home directory, which is the default path for `scp` to operate in.